# javascript Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

```
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'vertical',
        loop: true,
      
        // If we need pagination
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
      
        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      
        // And if we need scrollbar
        scrollbar: {
          el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        },
      });
```

```
it says that error is in last line:
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at script.js:43:5)
I have bootstap,swiper-bundle in my project
I'm really confused

Comment: In order to understand fully, we need the full script. Maybe paste it to Pastebin and link it here.

Comment: @RaulChiarella No, we do NOT need the full script, we need the MINIMAL amount of code to demonstrate the issue

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](https://jsbin.com/moxupogehe/1/edit?html,console,output). You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The error isn't in the last line, it will be a missing bracket at the end of an earlier function